# Center element's text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see, currently the labels are displayed to the top-left of the inputs - when checking a label element in dev tools, I can see that the labels have the same height and position as the inputs elements, but for some reason the label's text is displayed at the top of the element.

How do I centralize said text, in a way that it is centralized inside its label element and displayed to the center-left of the input fields?

```css
.new-food-form label { margin-right: 0.5vw; }

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .new-food-form > div > :nth-child(n+4) { margin-top: 1vw; }
    .confirm-new-food { margin-top: 1vw; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .new-food-buttons .row { justify-content: space-between; }
    .food-item-row > div, .new-food-form input, .new-food-form select { margin-bottom: 1.5vw; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body class="m-3">
        <form class="new-food container-fluid needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="new-food-form col-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-name${uniqueId}">Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-name" required type="text" id="new-food-name${uniqueId}" placeholder="Food name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-calories${uniqueId}">Calories:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-calories" required type="number" id="new-food-calories${uniqueId}" placeholder="Calories (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-proteins${uniqueId}">Proteins:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-proteins" required type="number" id="new-food-proteins${uniqueId}" placeholder="Proteins (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-carbs${uniqueId}">Carbs:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-carbs" required type="number" id="new-food-carbs${uniqueId}" placeholder="Carbs (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-fats${uniqueId}">Fats:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-fats" required type="number" id="new-food-fats${uniqueId}" placeholder="Fats (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
                            <label for="new-food-portion${uniqueId}">Portion:</label>
                            <select class="form-select new-food-portion" required id="new-food-portion${uniqueId}">
                                <option selected disabled>Select portion type</option>
                                <option value="1 unit">1 unit</option>
                                <option value="100 g">100 g</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="new-food-buttons col-12 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button class="cancel-new-food col-5 col-lg-12 btn btn-danger" type="button">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"></path>
                                <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"></path>
                            </svg> Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button class="confirm-new-food col-5 col-lg-12 btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z"/>
                            </svg> Create
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you are trying to achieve:
[image]

And since you are using bootstrap, you can just add

```
align-items-center
```

this class to

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex">
```

and make it like:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
```

align-items-center will make sure that all the items in your flex are vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77411576/1921385) you can add the class `align-items-center` to achieve this but note that your `margin-bottom: 1.5vw;` on the `.new-food-form input` will put things out of line so you should also apply this style to `.new-food-form label` too:

```css
.new-food-form label { margin-right: 0.5vw; }

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .new-food-form > div > :nth-child(n+4) { margin-top: 1vw; }
    .confirm-new-food { margin-top: 1vw; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .new-food-buttons .row { justify-content: space-between;}
    .food-item-row > div, .new-food-form label, .new-food-form input, .new-food-form select { margin-bottom: 1.5vw; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body class="m-3">
        <form class="new-food container-fluid needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="new-food-form col-12 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-name${uniqueId}">Name:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-name" required type="text" id="new-food-name${uniqueId}" placeholder="Food name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-calories${uniqueId}">Calories:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-calories" required type="number" id="new-food-calories${uniqueId}" placeholder="Calories (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-proteins${uniqueId}">Proteins:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-proteins" required type="number" id="new-food-proteins${uniqueId}" placeholder="Proteins (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-carbs${uniqueId}">Carbs:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-carbs" required type="number" id="new-food-carbs${uniqueId}" placeholder="Carbs (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-fats${uniqueId}">Fats:</label>
                            <input class="form-control new-food-fats" required type="number" id="new-food-fats${uniqueId}" placeholder="Fats (in grams, only numbers)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <label for="new-food-portion${uniqueId}">Portion:</label>
                            <select class="form-select new-food-portion" required id="new-food-portion${uniqueId}">
                                <option selected disabled>Select portion type</option>
                                <option value="1 unit">1 unit</option>
                                <option value="100 g">100 g</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="new-food-buttons col-12 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button class="cancel-new-food col-5 col-lg-12 btn btn-danger" type="button">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"></path>
                                <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"></path>
                            </svg> Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button class="confirm-new-food col-5 col-lg-12 btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M10.97 4.97a.75.75 0 0 1 1.07 1.05l-3.99 4.99a.75.75 0 0 1-1.08.02L4.324 8.384a.75.75 0 1 1 1.06-1.06l2.094 2.093 3.473-4.425a.267.267 0 0 1 .02-.022z"/>
                            </svg> Create
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```